# Authentication required by wireless network appears multiple times

Tags: wireless, notification, authentication, bug-reporting, system-settings

Sometimes when I don't use my Ubuntu for a long time - maybe a day, I can see the popup showing

> **Authentication required by wireless network**

There's obviously some wireless connects and disconnects. But the main problem is that sometimes I find **tens of these popups**, and all of them I need to **close manually** (ok, I can write a script, but seriously..)

Is there any configuration to show **only one such popup**?

Comment: There's already a bug report for the subject: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/912702

Answer (score 0):

One useful answer from that bug thread is:

> Workaround for not nm-applet asking for the keyring all the time is to
>   go to NetworkManager (nm-connection-editor) & remove wireless networks
>   that are not currently in use or those wireless networks one doesn't
>   have access to.

Comment: The cause for that misbehavior is usually when something happens to the Wireless/Router. One doesn't want to turn off the wireless in that case.